# How do I get the info of the row where the trigger is executing?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm doing a code where I delete a row from the my database and then the trigger save that row into another table. 
My question is how can I get the id of the row I have just deleted?

The rest of the code is in php but the trigger has to be programmed in mysql.

Comment: You reference the record in the trigger by the keyword `OLD`. For instance `OLD.id` is the id of the record that is being deleted

Comment: So something like INSERT INTO caja_fb VALUES (OLD.id) would be correct?

Comment: Yes, something like that is how you do it. There are examples in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Ok, thak you very much!